# Sending notifications to multiples users from Oracle database

Tags: php, laravel, oracle

In Laravel I am sending email notifications to users from an Oracle database. The connection with Oracle is OK but when trying to send email notifications to users I get the following error:

> Call to undefined method stdClass::routeNotificationFor()  in
>   my_project/vendor
>   /laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/Channels/MailChannel.php

My notification class is as follow:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use App\User;

class Expired extends Notification
{
    use Queueable; 

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct( )
    { 
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {


    return ['mail']; 
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                    ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

This is how I send notifications:

```
<?php
$end = Carbon::now()->addDays(15)->format('Y-m-d h:m:s');
$users = DB::select("select email from user_  where val_to >= '$end ' group by email   ");
```

Notification::send($users, new Expired($users));

Comment: Your user model should use notifiable,  I would first check there.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer

Comment: Hello ! Still need help there plese. Thanks

Comment: Best Joseph, What does your User look like?

Comment: @NiteRain Thanks for your reply. I was using the wrong Model. I have created a new one for the table i am using and now my users are notifiables as you said. However, i still have another  error: InvalidArgumentException
Driver [email] not supported.  in   My_Project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Notifications\ChannelManager.php

Comment: Does your .env look like what is set up in config/mail.php for email?

Comment: If you notice in that file it says the only supported drivers are smtp, sendmail, mailgun, ses, sparkpost, log and array.  I am wondering if something set it to email, which isn't supported.

Comment: This is my .env code to set MAIL_DRIVER:   

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=user
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls